# Which units are most effective at destroying buildings?

Tags: halo-wars-2

In Halo Wars (1) I use to enjoy a good hit&run tactic on an enemy base early in the game to destroy their generator(s) with cyclops's.

In Halo Wars 2, cyclops's are more anti-tank units then building destroyers.

Which units are the best to take down buildings for both UNSC and Banished?

Answer (score 1):

For the Banished, the [Locust unit](https://www.halopedia.org/Type-30_Locust#Halo_Wars_2) is specifically for destroying buildings.  A bunch of these against a building should take it down pretty fast.

As for the USMC, I don't think there is an actual unit specifically for targeting buildings.  However, Scorpions are probably the best at taking out buildings, or Grizzly Tanks if playing as Sgt. Forge.  Upgrading the Scorpion tanks to have their Canister Shell ability makes them pretty devastating against buildings, especially when you have multiple tanks fire all at one time at a building.  Marines when upgraded to have rocket launchers make them pretty effective at this as well, but you need a lot of them focused on a building at a time.

The Vulture unit is very strong as well, but due to the amount of man power it takes to create one, it makes it difficult to get multiples of them.

Comment: +1 but none of those units are available early game. Best I have so far is ODST drops with demo charges

Comment: @Vahx Wasn't sure if you were looking in general or for early on in the game.  I'm not sure what would be best for early game.  Perhaps marines if you upgrade them fast enough.